# Multiple statements in a where clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to create a where clause that has 2 statements that work together and then a separate statement that works by itself if it meets a certain criteria

I've tried CASE statements, AND's, OR's and still nothing works

```
WHERE HB.CreatedByDate = @ReportDateN AND HB.Date = @ReportDateN - 1
```

So this code is my current where clause that get's me results that have the CreatedByDate equal to the variable @ReportDateN but also have the regular date equal to the variable @ReportDateN except it minuses one day.

This by itself does what I want it to do but I'd like to add some more.

I want to make it so if a variable called @WeekDay = 'Monday' then to subtract 3 from @ReportDateN in the second part instead of just 1.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Just replace `1` with `CASE @WeekDay WHEN 'Monday' THEN 3 ELSE 1 END`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   WHERE HB.CreatedByDate = @ReportDateN
     AND HB.DATE = CASE 
        WHEN @Weekday = 'Monday'
            THEN (@ReportDateN - 3)
        ELSE (@ReportDateN - 1)
         END
```

This can also be done by combining OR Statements

```
WHERE HB.CreatedByDate = @ReportDateN AND 
      (
       @Weekday = 'Monday' AND HB.Date = (@ReportDateN - 3) 
      )
   OR
      (
        @Weekday != 'Monday' AND HB.Date = (@ReportDateN - 1) 
      )
```

Just for Reference, note that the following will not work:

```
 WHERE CASE @Weekday = 'Monday' THEN .... ELSE ..... END
```

EDIT: Per op's comment below:

```
WHERE HB.CreatedByDate = @ReportDateN AND 
      (
       @Weekday = 'Monday' AND (
                                HB.Date = (@ReportDateN - 3) OR
                                HB.Date = (@ReportDateN - 2) OR
                                HB.Date = (@ReportDateN - 1) 
                               )  
      )
   OR
      (
        @Weekday != 'Monday' AND HB.Date = (@ReportDateN - 1) 
      )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and everyone else. This works the way I ask but I'd like to maybe add one more thing. Is it possible to get the results in between the 3 days I'm taking away if you get me?

So say It's a Monday and I take away 3 days to get to the Friday. Would I be able to get Saturday and Sunday results?

Again thanks for your help!

Comment: @ChungWill I updated one of the solutions I provided above. If you would like to use the other solution I provided, I suggest you play with it on your own and come back if you need help.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. I'm still early days learning SQL and sometimes trying to figure out the right logic to do what I wanna do confuses the hell outta me so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
WHERE
     HB.CreatedByDate = @ReportDateN AND
     (
        @WeekDay = 'Monday' AND HB.Date = @ReportDateN - 3
        OR
        HB.Date = @ReportDateN - 1
    )
```